# How to get size (Content-Length) of the request before sending with $http / AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use $http service to send some data to backend using FormData:

```
fd = new FormData()
fd.append('message[is_send]', true)
fd.append('message[to]', toEmails)
fd.append('message[cc]', ccEmails)
fd.append('message[bcc]', bccEmails)
fd.append('message[subject]', @message.subject) if @message.subject
fd.append('message[body]', @message.content) if @message.content

message.attachments.forEach (attachment) ->
  fd.append('message[attachments][]', attachment)

$http
  url: "/messages"
  method: 'POST'
  headers:
    'Content-Type': undefined
  data: fd
```

Backend must have data size limit (for example, 10 mb), and I need to calculate size of data before sending in order to prevent user and show some notification. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The verification is running in backend, right?

Comment: Yes right. I want to forbid user to send big files on the client size.

Comment: Right, you can check the size in backend and return the message when the size is big. I not understand why the angular is responsible for this

Comment: In your case I will do useless request and user will be waiting, I don't want it.

Comment: But your backend has the information of size response. In the cycle execution is: $http request > backend process the request and send response > $http request receive the response of backend and working with this. In your situation, you want obtains the size of json before resquest?